# unknownElement in XML response for ruleset executed by Business Rules on Bluemix

Tags: ibm-cloud, business-rules

I executed a ruleset on the Business Rules service on Bluemix. The XML response has an element called "unknownElement" which is not in the WSDL definition.

> < DecisionServiceResponse
>   xmlns="http://www.ilog.com/rules/DecisionService" >
>
> ```
> < ilog.rules.outputString > ... < /ilog.rules.outputString >
>
> < ilog.rules.firedRulesCount>  ... < /ilog.rules.firedRulesCount >
>
> < yourResponse xmlns="..">
>
>       < unknownElement xmlns="" >
>
>        ...
>
>       < /unknownElement >
>
> < /yourResponse >
> ```
>
> < /DecisionServiceResponse >

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This occurred because I defined the ruleset parameter type in the XML schema (XSD), but did not declare a global element of that type.

The type of the parameter, Foo, was defined in the XSD XOM as follows:

> ```
> < schema xmlns=.. xmlns:tns=.. targetNamespace=.. >
>
>    < complexType name="Foo">
>
>       < attribute name="bar" type="string"></attribute >
>
>    < /complexType >
>
> < /schema >
> ```

To resolve the problem, I added a global element for that type in the XSD:

> ```
> < schema xmlns=.. xmlns:tns=.. targetNamespace=.. >
>
>    < element name="FooElement" type="tns:Foo"></element >
>
>    < complexType name="Foo">
>
>       < attribute name="bar" type="string"></attribute >
>
>    < /complexType >
>
> < /schema >
> ```